# Can connect do SQL Server Database without Server Login - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use AD groups to access SQL Server and Databases in this server. I have tested that if I deleted login from Server I still can connect to Database which i have defined User. Why this permission still exists? I thought that if I drop login from server i wouldn't access to database which was mapped from this login.

Comment: `LOGIN` and `USER`s are different objects. I don't really follow what you are asking here.

Comment: If you're using AD Groups, it's possible the user is member of more than one group that has DB access.